# How to fix problem of background-image not showing up in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a background image that will be dimmed with white text overlay. However, the background image is not showing up.

When I inspect the page in Chrome, there is an error shown at background-image.

```
/*HTML*/
<div class="main-body1">
    <h1>Innovating Moldova. Thinking bigger.</h1>
    <h2>A nonprofit collaboration between professionals and 
    organizations focused on benefitting the economic state of the 
    Republic of Moldova.</h2>
</div>



/*CSS*/
.main-body1 {
    padding: 10rem 5%;
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;}

.main-body1:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("../images/chisinau.jpeg") no-repeat;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1; /*Make sure the image sits below the content  */}
```

Comment: Just remove `no-repeat` from `background-image`

Answer (score 3):

`no-repeat` is a valid value for the `background-repeat` property, but not for the `background-image` property.

It can also be used in the shorthand property `background`. So to fix your problem, either go

```
background-image: url("../images/chisinau.jpeg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

or use the shorthand property `background`:

```
background: url("../images/chisinau.jpeg") no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, i just removed **no-repeat** and add background repeat as separate `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

```css
.main-body1 {
    padding: 10rem 5%;
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;}

.main-body1:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("https://images3.alphacoders.com/117/117169.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
```

```html
<div class="main-body1">
    <h1>Innovating Moldova. Thinking bigger.</h1>
    <h2>A nonprofit collaboration between professionals and 
    organizations focused on benefitting the economic state of the 
    Republic of Moldova.</h2>
</div>
```